# ViewController creation process using storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

For the following steps:

1. drag two view controllers using storyboard, add a button on the first VC
2. `ctrl` drag the button on the first VC to the second VC and choose present segue
3. embed first VC with navigation controller

My questions are:

1. What happens under the hood when program starts? In particular, how and where will be the first and second VC created?
2. If not same, what's the difference compared with code below?

   `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController`

Swift code will be preferred but Objective-C is also fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you have shown instantiates a view controller but doesn't present it in any way.  ctrl-dragging and creating a segue will instantiate the view controller and present it when the button is tapped.  The first view controller will be created by the Swift runtime equivalent of `main()`.  The second view controller will be created when the segue is triggered

Comment: @Paulw11, I didn't write down the present code to focus on the instantiation part. So my question is, is the same`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` function got called when I do that using storyboard?

Comment: Probably the same method is called. Why does it matter?  I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @Paulw11, just understand the difference between code way and storyboard way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing using:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
```

is that you are doing what the storyboard is supposed to do. You are forcefully preparing for the segue. When you simply connect the two views using the segue on the storyboard, you are telling the compiler that the connection exists. When you run the code the second viewcontroller is instantiated the instant you click on the button and performs a prepareForSegue.

All in all, its all about manually overriding the delegate methods that are called when the storyboard works.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly the same as storyboard since you won't call `prepareForSegue` on your first viewController if you instantiate the second one directly. `performSegueWithIdentifier` is useful in this case. Also, `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is only called when the segue is launched from the storyboard.